# Transformar Colunas em Linha em sql

Tags: sql

Bom dia Pessoal,

Tenha a seguinte query:

```
DECLARE @DTINICIAL AS DATE
DECLARE @DTFINAL AS  DATE

SET @DTINICIAL = '202101[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]01'
SET @DTFINAL = '20210630'

SELECT 

    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE WHEN ZB0.ZB0_NATURE ='910074' THEN ZB0.ZB0_VLTRAN else 0 END)) CRED_MERC_LOGISTICA,
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE WHEN ZB0.ZB0_NATURE ='910075' THEN ZB0.ZB0_VLTRAN else 0 END)) CRED_MERC_INDUSTRIA,
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE WHEN ZB0.ZB0_NATURE ='910076' THEN ZB0.ZB0_VLTRAN else 0 END)) ESTORNO_ICMS,
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE WHEN ZB0.ZB0_NATURE ='910077' THEN ZB0.ZB0_VLTRAN else 0 END)) CRED_GARANTIA,
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE WHEN ZB0.ZB0_NATURE ='910078' THEN ZB0.ZB0_VLTRAN else 0 END)) CRED_CARTAO_CREDITO
FROM 

    ZB0010 ZB0
WHERE
    1=1
    AND ZB0.ZB0_DATA BETWEEN @DTINICIAL AND @DTFINAL
```

Nota: Conforme a imagem em anexo estou precisando inverter o resultado ou seja transformar está coluna em linha ai a tabela ficará com apenas 2 colunas nome da conta e o valor de cada uma..

Observação: desde já agradeço a atenção

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: primeiro, ah o clássico `where 1=1`, não via isso há muito tempo :)
pode fazer `sum` num select separado e juntar tudo com `union` e pronto, vai ter o resultado em linhas diferentes

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente costuma ser mais dificil transformar linhas em colunas. Pode partir a query e unir com UNION ALL, não sei se é eficiente para a quantidade de dados que possuiu, mas nada como testar.

Fiz apenas para 2 dos valores que pretende, basta completar ocm os outros. Pode validar por favor?

```
                DECLARE @DTINICIAL AS DATE
                DECLARE @DTFINAL AS  DATE

                SET @DTINICIAL = '202101[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]01'
                SET @DTFINAL = '20210630'

                SELECT 
                    'CRED_MERC_LOGISTICA' AS DESCRICAO,
                    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE WHEN ZB0.ZB0_NATURE ='910074' THEN ZB0.ZB0_VLTRAN else 0 END)) CRED_MERC_LOGISTICA,
                FROM 

                    ZB0010 ZB0
                WHERE
                    1=1
                    AND ZB0.ZB0_DATA BETWEEN @DTINICIAL AND @DTFINAL

                UNION ALL

                SELECT 
                    'CRED_MERC_INDUSTRIA' AS DESCRICAO,
                    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE WHEN ZB0.ZB0_NATURE ='910075' THEN ZB0.ZB0_VLTRAN else 0 END)) CRED_MERC_INDUSTRIA,
                FROM 

                    ZB0010 ZB0
                WHERE
                    1=1
                    AND ZB0.ZB0_DATA BETWEEN @DTINICIAL AND @DTFINAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Mario,

Obrigado por responder, mas imagina que esta informação será dinâmica ai não vai rolar usar o Union eu ate tinha pensado nisso funciona porem a query vai ficar enorme e vai afetar o desempenho da consulta. Mas obrigado por responder.